# What is the best way to store a guid?

Tags: 7

I found that the best way to store a guid is as a char(36) data type for MySQL.
What is the equivalent to char(36) in drupal 7?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/159605

Answer (score 0):

In terms of core function I don't think there's a lot of choice you can have.  You'd have to use the "text" field type and limit to 36 chars.